# If unique subgroups of order $m$ and $n$ exist, is subgroup of order $nm$ unique if it exists?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose that $G$ is a group and has two unique subgroups of order $m$ and $n$ respectively, where $m$ and $n$ are different and greater than $1$.  If there exists a subgroup of order $mn$, then does it has to be unique?

It seems that the statement is true when $G$ is abelian: $G$ can be represented by the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and uniqueness of group of order $mn$ can be shown if it exists.
And I thought it would be false when $G$ is not abelian so tried to find a counterexample, but couldn't have found any.

Is there any counterexample for this statement? Or could you help me with proving this?

Comment: I would recommend writing a small piece of code in GAP or Magma and starting with a brute force search of small groups.

Comment: Thank you! I will try GAP next time

Answer (score 6):

When you say "2 unique subgroups of order $n$ and $m$ respectively", then I guess you mean a unique subgroup of order $m$ and a unique subgroup of order $n$.

If you had allowed $m=n$, then we could have taken the quaternion group $Q_8$ is a counterexample with $m=n=2$.

Otherwise, we can take $G = Q_8 \times C_3$, with $m=2$ and $n=6$. There are unique subgroups of order $2$ and $6$, but three subgroups of order $12$.

Comment: The OP states explicitly that $m, n$ are different.

Comment: @AJY Yes OK, but it was considering the case $m=n$ that helped me think of an example!

Comment: Thank you! The second one is what i was looking for

Comment: @DerekHolt can i ask you one more? If H is a unique sub group of order n and K is a unique subgroup of order m then the internal direct product HK be a unique subgroup of order nm/gcd(n,m) ? Actually this was what i was curious about at first, but somehow i just moved on to the case of nm. Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: No, the order of $HK$ is not necessarily equal to $nm/\gcd(n,m)$.

Comment: Are there counterexamples with gcd$(m,n)=1$?

Comment: @NickyHekster I was wondering about that. I would guess yes, but it might be hard to find an example.

Comment: Yes, so maybe the suggestion of Greg Martin above would be worthwhile - applying GAP or Magma to find counterexamples.

Comment: @NickyHekster Perhaps, but I am afraid that counterexamples might be quite large.

Comment: @DerekHolt you are right i was confused. I meant mn divided by the order of H∩K.

Comment: Yes, since $H$ and $K$ are the unique subgroups of those orders, they must both be normal subgroups of $G$, and so $HK$ is a normal subgroup of order $mn/|H \cap K|$. But it is not clear that it is the unique subgroup of that order (although I don't know a counterexample).

Comment: @DerekHolt I see. Thank you for your effort though